# Validation for Picklist Value from MultiPicklist Value

Tags: salesforce, formula, apex

In multi picklist i have = A, B and C
In picklist i have D

I need salesforce validation for this so that only selected values in multi picklist will come to picklist.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Field dependencies for this

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_simple_app_adv_field_dependencies.htm